# PayPal refunds not generating IPN anymore

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a web site thats been operating for months, if not years.  It takes payments via PayPal.  IPNs are used to track the payment status against an order.

If the paypal account owner issues a refund, the IPN from that is tracked, and the order updated with the amount refunded.

Now: The problem:  This was all working in February 2015.  But since then I have made 4 refunds (buy logging into the PayPal website and refunding).  Each one was days apart.  In each case they were partial refunds.

In all cases the monies have reached the recipient, and logged transactions IDs etc in PayPal.

The first one, I never received the IPN.

The second one I did received the IPN (and decided the first one must have been a glitch, unusal though it would seem)

However the third and fourth also have not generated an IPN that I received.

From looking at the Apache logs, there appears to not have been even an attempt from notify.paypal.com that Apache received.

So I am much puzzled, have googled around but not found anything.  Can anyone suggest what I have missed that have caused these IPNs to stop?

Perhaps I should add that I continue to receive all the payment notification IPNs just fine.  It seems to be just the refunds that I miss.

I thought at one time there was a flag about IPNs in settings, but I can't see it anywhere in the new web interface.

Regards
Monathan

Comment: Did you check the PayPal IPN History?

Comment: Great Idea... But ... I can't even find anything on IPN History in the new PayPal website... Not even in Help.  Can you tell me how to find it?

Comment: Perhaps it's not clear from above, but when the initial payment is generated, i DO receive the IPN at that point.  It's only on the subsequent  refund that it doesn't.

Comment: From the new design if you go to the More menu at the top you can then Switch to Classic.  Then you can look at IPN History the way you used to.  It sounds like your IPN script must be failing when a refund type hits it, but it's fine otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the tip .. but how does "IPN script failing" square with "The apache logs don't show anything"?  Thats what is puzzling me.

Comment: The first step is always to check PayPal IPN History and see if the IPNs are getting sent.