# PayPal Sandbox IPN Refund issue

Tags: paypal-ipn

I've been testing PayPal payments and received the IPN as expected on my staging/sandbox environment. However I noticed that the IPN for refunds are not being sent. I have verified this against my application as well as the Sandbox business account and the IPN history only shows the payment but not the refunded IPN. The payment history do however reflect the refunded status of the payments.

Can someone tell me if this is an expected behaviour since both the IPN history and the payment records do not tally? Thanks.

This is similar to the issue reported on but there's been no reply since: [PayPal refunds not generating IPN anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476606/paypal-refunds-not-generating-ipn-anymore)

Answer (score -1):

I would advise you to get in touch with the PayPal team to check on this. We will need more information to check on this. You may get back to us via the link below.

https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask

Thank you.